# How to Override Chrome Extension Styles

Tags: javascript, userjs

How to override the styles of Chrome extensions like Midnight Lizard or Dark Reader?

I'm working on a USERJS, and some styles are getting overridden by these dark mode extensions. Their styles always seem to have the highest priority. I've tried deleting style tags and removing document.styleSheets, but it doesn't seem to work. How can I either delete or override their styles within the USERJS environment?

English is not my native language, and this article has been translated by CHATGPT, so please bear with me.